# I'm telling a friend that "not seeing them changed things". Is this correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I couldn't see my grandchildren last Easter because of the covid. I'm telling a friend that '**not seeing them changed things**' (i.e., I will have to make new plans to visit them instead). Is the statement in bold correct?

Comment: I removed the capital letters.  Telling your friend this seems fine, but SHOUTING it in her face isn't right!  (on the internet, all capital letters mean shouting)

Comment: "it changed things" normally refers to a lasting and serious change, not just requiring to book a different train. So it may or may not apply.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine.  It doesn't say *how* it changed things, so it is quite vague. It doesn't say specifically that you will make new plans.  It doesn't say what or how things changed, so if you want your friend to know the details you'll have to tell them.